# Random shadow appears out of nowhere on supposedly square elements, making everything misalign

Tags: css

I am trying to create a very precise matrix on top of a board. I know it's 48cm tall and wide, and therefore I am using the metric system. According to my code, they should align perfectly, but I'm experiencing some weird issues, which might be related to anti-aliasing. I honestly have no idea.

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

and then at this code: https://jsfiddle.net/o21rdwvw/3/

I use two methods:

```
background: black;

//one of these according to horizontal/vertical
width: 4px;
height: 4px;
```

and

```
outline: 4px solid black;
```

As you can see in this image, that is not really the case. It looks like some of the boxes has a shadow, with the HEX color `#576c73`, which has no relation to the color `#000000` (unless the browsers somehow pick a shadow, which is some % brighter or darker than the original color).

I have tried changing the units around to pixel (even and odd numbers) as well as remove the `transform: scale()`, but none of them changed anything.

What kind of wizardry is this, and how can I prevent them from messing up my alignment?

EDIT: As you can see, the small boxes are differently sized, even though all the browsers report they're the same size. The bottom one is square, whereas the top and middle ones are slightly shorter:

[image]

EDIT 2: It appears to be a browser problem. Edge does not render the actual shadow, for example. It's just not as tall or wide as the others.

Comment: Didn't even took time to check in dev tools, but don't use `cm` unit if you are targeting screens. Browsers have internally some max precision set to length units (IIRC in webkit and Blink, it's about 0.5 px precision) and they will happily round your values with really weird rules. Using a `cm` unit means that you will always have such floating points that will get rounded, to you can't really know which value (e.g the rendering values are not always the same as the one reported by getComputedStyle). So to avoid this nightmare, use only px, and even only rounded px.

Comment: @Kaiido I do realise that, and I did state that I did try pixels and metric units. It made no difference what so ever, so that isn't the problem here.

Comment: Setting font-size to 0 on everything helped them align better for me as I scrolled down the page, but didn't fix the .5 px

Comment: @JasonB Oh you're right, setting the font-size to 0 does help it, yet I can still see some appear to be smaller.

Comment: Nevermind, it appears they are all the same size (took screenshot and checked in Photoshop). It would also appear that the box sizes are exactly the same, but some of the dividers still have the shadow, while some don't. I can't really see a pattern, so I'm guessing it's a browser related issue?

Comment: I think it's the half pixel thing. I'm with Kaiido - If it has to be right on, you use px and no scale and do the math to ensure there are no 1/2 pixels. Messed with your fiddle in Chrome and got rid of the fuzzy edges https://jsfiddle.net/6pvrrzmk/

Comment: Seting line-height to 0 and converting all units to rounded px seems to avoid the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/o21rdwvw/6/

Comment: Odd. I really wanted to use metric units, but I guess it's a bit buggy. Thanks!